# what is this font (thank you)?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

[image]

Can somebody tell me whats this font name? :)

Answer (score 2):

This font appears to be Impact.

Comment: I was going to say "gender-queer", but that was WAY too snarky!  :)